# Does a convergent improper integral equal its Cauchy Principal Value?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

I was working through the section in my analysis book on improper integrals, and I understand that convergence is a stronger requirement than having a Cauchy principal value, but I was wondering about how the principal value would apply to convergent integrals and couldn't find any theorems that addressed it so I thought I'd pose my question here.

Let $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx$ be an improper integral--improper due to the fact that $a=-\infty$ and $b=\infty$ (case I), or that $f$ has a singularity at a point $c\in(a,b)$ (case II)--which converges. Does the value of the integral equal its Cauchy principal value? That is, does $$\lim_{r\to-\infty}\int_r^0 f(x) \ dx+\lim_{s\to\infty}\int_0^s f(x) \ dx=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^a f(x) \ dx$$ in case I, and $$\lim_{s\to c^-}\int_a^s f(x) \ dx+\lim_{r\to c^+}\int_r^b f(x) \ dx=\lim_{r\to0}\left[\int_a^{c-r} f(x) \ dx+\int_{c+r}^b f(x) \ dx\right]$$ in case II, provided both limits on the left exist and are finite?

After writing it out it seems like the answer would be yes through basic variable substitution, linearity of the limit, and the interval additivity property of the integral. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes. Nothing to add to the final paragraph of your question. :)